# How to assign class for each id, based on multiple conditions

Tags: r, if-statement, classification, multiple-conditions

I am relatively new to R and get a lot of help from stackoverflow!!

I have over 1000 person's data expressing certain conditions.
Each variables consist of either continuous variables or categorized variables.
I have to label each person a **'class' (class A, B, C)** based on combinations of 3 conditions (Q1, Q2, Q3)
But, each conditions are decided by variable's vlaue.
It is a bit complicated.

For example,

My data are like this.

```
       var1    var2    var3    var4    var5
id1     1       10       1       0      1.5
id2     0       20       0       2      2.4
id3     0       15       0       1      3.5
id4     1       30       1       1      2.1
.
.
id1000  1       25       1       0      1.2
```

And 3 conditions (Q1,Q2,Q3) are like this.

```
        Q1          Q2       Q3     
var1    1           .        0
var2   15>      15≤ & <25    >25
var3    1           .        0
var4    2           1        0
var5   <2.0         .       ≥2.0
```

Class is decided by followings for each id

```
-If two or more Q1 conditions exist  -> class A
-'one Q1 and more than one Q2' or 'more than two Q2' -> class B
-else -> class C
```

For example,
id1 variables (V1~V5) conditions are Q1, Q1, Q1, Q3, Q1, respectively. Because more than two Q1 exist in id1, class of id1 will be A.

I googled many days but hard to figure out solutions.
If the number of conditions are two (Q1, Q2), it would be much easier task but unfortunatley there are 3 conditions.
I try to apply ifelse statement, but in my opinion, it's not sutiable in this case

Comment: Could you clarify the class decision logic with an example? I don't quite understand `two or more Q1` or `one Q1 and one in Q2`, `two in Q2`. What does the `two or more`, `one`, `two` exactly mean?

Comment: @YHJang 
I will revise it.
It means if a person meets more than two Q1 condition.
For example, id1's variables (V1~V5) conditions are 
Q1, Q1, Q1, Q3, Q1. 
Because more than two Q1, class of id1 is A.

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat complicated, but you should be able to use the `case_when()` function from the [dplyr package](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/) to apply your 'rules' to each id, i.e.

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- read.table(text = "       var1    var2    var3    var4    var5
id1     1       10       1       0      1.5
id2     0       20       0       2      2.4
id3     0       15       0       1      3.5
id4     1       30       1       1      2.1", header = TRUE)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(class = case_when(sum(var1 == 1, var2 > 15, var3 == 1, var4 == 2, var5 < 2.0) >= 2 ~ "class A",
                           sum(var1 == 1, var2 > 15, var3 == 1, var4 == 2, var5 < 2.0) == 1 &
                             sum((var2 >= 15 & var2 < 25), var4 == 1) > 1 ~ "class B",
                           TRUE ~ "class C"))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 6
#> # Rowwise: 
#>    var1  var2  var3  var4  var5 class  
#>   <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <chr>  
#> 1     1    10     1     0   1.5 class A
#> 2     0    20     0     2   2.4 class A
#> 3     0    15     0     1   3.5 class C
#> 4     1    30     1     1   2.1 class A
```

If you change var4 to 1 for id2, that id would then fall into the class B criteria using your rules:

```r
df2 <- read.table(text = "       var1    var2    var3    var4    var5
id1     1       10       1       0      1.5
id2     0       20       0       1      2.4
id3     0       15       0       1      3.5
id4     1       30       1       1      2.1", header = TRUE)
all.equal(df, df2)
#> [1] "Component \"var4\": Mean relative difference: 0.5"

df2 %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(class = case_when(sum(var1 == 1, var2 > 15, var3 == 1, var4 == 2, var5 < 2.0) >= 2 ~ "class A",
                           sum(var1 == 1, var2 > 15, var3 == 1, var4 == 2, var5 < 2.0) == 1 &
                             sum((var2 >= 15 & var2 < 25), var4 == 1) > 1 ~ "class B",
                           TRUE ~ "class C"))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 6
#> # Rowwise: 
#>    var1  var2  var3  var4  var5 class  
#>   <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <chr>  
#> 1     1    10     1     0   1.5 class A
#> 2     0    20     0     1   2.4 class B
#> 3     0    15     0     1   3.5 class C
#> 4     1    30     1     1   2.1 class A
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Wow. It works perfectly. I really appreciated this answer.
Thnaks a lot!

Comment: During running this code, I find out that 2nd conditions of 'case_when' code should be connected with '|' not '&'.  
 sum(var1==1 ....var5<2.0)==1   |    sum ((var2....var4==1)>1 ~ 'class B' 
Anyway,  thanks a lot. I cannot express my gratitude enough!