# Way to create new variable based on the result of multiple imputation

Tags: r, missing-data, imputation, r-mice

Create new variable for categorization after multiple imputation.

I have over 1000 person's data expressing certain conditions. Each variables consist of either continuous variables or categorized variables. I have to label each person a 'class' (class A, B, C) based on several conditions. Each conditions are decided by variable's vlaue. (Already got answered, [How to assign class for each id, based on multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76286043/how-to-assign-class-for-each-id-based-on-multiple-conditions#comment134532036_76286262)

My data (**df**) are like this.

```
       var1    var2    var3    var4    var5
id1     1       10       1       0      1.5
id2     0       NA       0       2      NA
id3     0       15      NA       1      3.5
id4     1       NA       1       1      2.1
.
.
id1000  1       25       1       0      1.2
```

I am trying multiple imputation for missing values and want to make a new variable ('class') based on the result of multiple imputation.

I firstly attempted to do with following codes, similar to 1st part of the chapter 6.4 'Derived variables' of 'Flexible imputation of missing data, 2nd ed.' by Stef van Buuren. https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/sec-knowledge.html

```
imp1 <- mice(df, maxit = 5, pred = pred ,method =meth, post=post, print = TRUE, allow.na=TRUE)
    
long1 <- mice::complete(imp1, "long", include=TRUE)
    
long2<-long1 %>% 
       rowwise() %>% 
       mutate(class = case_when(sum(var1 == 1, var2 > 15, var3 == 1, var4 == 2, var5 < 2.0) >= 2 ~ 'class A',
                       sum(var1 == 1, var2 > 15, var3 == 1, var4 == 2, var5 < 2.0) == 1 &
                         sum((var2 >= 15 & var2 < 25), var4 == 1) > 1 ~ 'class B',
                       TRUE ~ 'class C')
    
 imp1.itt <- as.mids(long2)
```

Q1) I think this is not a bad solution and actually curious about this is a right solution.

Q2) I also wonder is there a way to use a **'passive imputation'**?

I treid as follows.

```
df1<-cbind(df, class=NA)

ini<-mice(df1, max=0, print=FALSE)

pred<-ini$predictorMatrix
pred[, c( 'class')]<-0  

meth<-ini$method     
meth['class']<-"~case_when(sum(var1 == 1, var2 > 15, var3 == 1, var4 == 2, var5 < 2.0) >= 2 ~ 'class A',
                           sum(var1 == 1, var2 > 15, var3 == 1, var4 == 2, var5 < 2.0) == 1 &
                             sum((var2 >= 15 & var2 < 25), var4 == 1) > 1 ~ 'class B',
                           TRUE ~ 'class C')"

imp <- mice(df1, maxit = 5, predictorMatrix = pred,method =meth,  
            print =  TRUE, allow.na=TRUE)
```

But during multiple imputation, I got stuck with error "Error in colMeans(as.matrix(imp[[j]]), na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric"

I wonder what is the problem. Whether compelx passive imputation code is a problem or is there any thing (or many things..) I miss.

Thanks.

If you need example dataset, I prepared as follows

```
df2 <- read.table(text = "       var1    var2    var3    var4    var5
id1     1       10       1       0      1.5
id2     0       20       0       1      2.4
id3     0       15       0       1      3.5
id4     1       30       1       1      2.1", header = TRUE)
```